# .net Core - SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, traefik

I am currently having some issues with our .Net Core services. I will start off with explaining our environment setup

We have multiple microservices (.Net Core Web API) in a docker swarm setup on a Linux CentOS box. There are multiple nodes in the swarm. A web front end is deployed as a service within the swarm.

We use [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) for load balancing and runs on the manager node. We recently added an SSL certificate for the swarm and this is when the problem started.

The issue I am seeing is when services in the swarm try and talk to each other. Independently the services work fine - The UI connects to all the APIs and they work fine. But when there is an internal connection from one API to another, I see the below error

```
SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

I referenced the below link and tried the configuration to pass the forwarded headers but that didnt seem to help [.NET Core behind Load Balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Currently, I am running out of options and need help to try and figure out how this can be resolved. Any suggestions are welcome and are highly appreciated.

Comment: did u found any solution for this issue. I think I'm also facing similar issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56862832/5420194)